# GPflow multi-class: How to squeeze many gp.predict_f_samples to obtain their probabilities?

Tags: tensorflow, gpflow

I classify MNIST digits and I want to sample the probabilities (*not* the latent function) for each class on multiple many times. However, `gp.predict_y` gives the probabilities just for one case.

Thus I take `f_samples = gp.predict_f_samples` which returns numerous examples from the underlying latent function.
**Now, how to 'squeeze' the `f_samples` through the robust_max likelihood?**

Code for my gp:

```
kernel = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(input_dim=128, ARD=ARD, active_dims=np.arange(128))\
       + gpflow.kernels.White(input_dim=128, active_dims=np.arange(128))

# Robustmax Multiclass Likelihood
  invlink = gpflow.likelihoods.RobustMax(10)  # Robustmax inverse link function
  likelihood = gpflow.likelihoods.MultiClass(10, invlink=invlink)  # Multiclass likelihood
  Z = x_train[::5].copy()  # inducing inputs

  gp = gpflow.models.SVGP(x_train, y_train, num_latent=10,
                          kern=kernel, Z=Z, likelihood=likelihood,
                          whiten=True, q_diag=True)
```

GPflow version: 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sampled you're no longer working with a probability distribution - you have actual values for each of your 10 latent functions. To convert a sample to probabilities over the classes  you can just apply the RobustMax function (probability 1-epsilon for the largest latent function, epsilon/9 for all the others) to the 10 values you get. E.g.

```
eps = 0.001
f_samples = gp.predict_f_samples(x_test, num_samples)
largests = np.argmax(f_samples , axis = 2)
prob_samples = (np.eye(10)[largests]*(1-eps-eps/9)+eps/9)
```

Note that the probabilities you get will all be 0.999 on one class and 0.0001 on all the others - that's what RobustMax is. If you're intending to average over your samples, you probably just want to call gp.predict_y(), which actually integrates the RobustMax over the probability distribution and can give you some smoother class probabilities if the latent means are close.